# change textarea value doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

So, what i'm trying to do is adding a Javascript snippet in wordpress admin new post page, so that when i click a button it fills up the CONTENT textarea where the body of the post goes. Adding it is not a problem, i've already done this, but for some reason filling up the content field doesn't work.

The textarea from the wordpress admin page is:

```
<textarea rows='10' class='theEditor' cols='40' name='content' tabindex='2' id='content'></textarea>
```

Also i tried to fill up the POST_TITLE input and it works fine. I know the problem might come from the JS scripts of wordpress for the content field, because it's not a simple textarea, it's a JS text editor. Any suggestions?
And the JS snippet is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("form").submit(function(){
        $("input[name$='post_title']").val("a letter");
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "testing";
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

PS: jquery library already included

Comment: you can just change `.innerHTML` to `.value`. It should work :)

Comment: Tried that, as i said it works for other textareas from that form but it doesn't work for content text editor, which in fact is a textarea linked to some javascript scripts

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set (or get) the value of an input type element, including `<textarea>` and `<select>`, like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $("input[name$='post_title']").val("a letter");
    $('#content').val("testing");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @flowerpower - Are you getting a JavaScript error?  Try wrapping all of the above code inside a `(function($) {` ...above code... `})(jQuery);` block, WordPress usually uses `.noConflict()` on the jQuery include.

Comment: No i don't get any error, i wrapped all the code inside what you gave me but had no luck at all.

Comment: @flowerpower - Is the `<form>` added to the page dynamically, via ajax for example?

Comment: No, it's just under the <script> tag, as i said $("input[name$='post_title']").val("a letter") works fine, the title input changes its value to "a letter" when i submit the form, the content textarea is the only one that's not working

Comment: @flowerpower - Is it possible there is more than one `id="content"` element?  That *really* sounds like your symptoms.

Comment: No, i checked that and it's only one, here's the whole div where the text editor is wrapped: http://pastebin.com/SrAmqYAu  .. it's copy paste as it is on wordpress admin post page

Comment: @flowerpower - I don't see a `<form>` in there...how is this related to your current code?

Comment: There is actually  a form on the same page, look here http://pastebin.com/Q17U6gZS

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix jQuery and standard dom calls? Try this:

```
$("#content").text("hi");
```

Worked fine for me from the Firebug console.

**Update**: Sorry guys, missed the part that it's TinyMCE we're talking about. Here's the code that should be used to update both the hidden textarea AND the visual editor itself:

```
jQuery("#content").text("Your text goes here");
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceSetContent', false, jQuery("#content").text());
```

For more info check out the [TinyMCE Commands API](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aCommands)

Comment: Sorry about that, missed the part where you said you work with the visual editor. Updated the post.